# Are there any Matchers available for the Faktor-IPS MessageList?

Tags: faktor-ips

I'm using hamcrest in JUnit-Tests. For the Java collections classes there are Matchers like `hasSize` available. Are there any Matchers available for the Faktor-IPS `org.faktorips.runtime.MessageList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are specific matchers for `org.faktorips.runtime.MessageList` in `de.faktorzehn.commons.ips.test.matcher.IpsMatchers` available.
Unfortunately this is not part of Faktor-IPS.

Answer (score 1):

With the upcoming release 21.12 ([RC3 Release Notes](https://www.faktorzehn.org/blog/version-21-12-0-rc03/)), a new package [faktorips-testsupport](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.faktorips/faktorips-testsupport) is released on Maven central, which includes Matchers for Messages, MessageLists and ValueSets.